# Holding output without printing till program termination

Tags: java

Is there a way to hold the output without printing and finally print it out when the program terminates ?

For example

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));       
int t= Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
for (int tc=0;tc<t;tc++)
{
   String st = br.readLine();
   int len= st.length();
   System.out.println(len); //I don't want this to be printed on screen till the for loop terminates
}
```

The output for the code would be

```
2
abcd
4
aac
3
```

while what I want is

```
2
abcd
aac
4
3
```

Is it possible to get this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Concatenate what you want to print, and print it after the loop

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
for (int tc=0;tc<t;tc++)
{
    // ...
    //System.out.println(len);
    sb.append(len).append("\\n");
}

System.out.println(sb.toString());
```

Comment: Thank you! That was neat. I had to put a single backslash instead of 2. That is, sb.append(len).append("\n");